# Does rejection of null hypothesis in multiple regression entail causation?

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value, causality

We make a model of the following form:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \epsilon
$$

and with $n=1,000$, $\hat\beta_1$ has a p-value <0.001.

If our data and data collection meets assumptions of multiple linear regression, we can say:

- If the population shows ***NO relationship*** between $x_1$ and $y$, then properly random samples of $n=1,000$ will show this degree of fit (or relationship) in <0.001 of the samples.

**What then are the *logically possible relationships* between $x_1$ and $y$?**

I see the following but want to know if there are others:

- If $\beta_1 = 0$:

  10. $x_1$ and $y$ are linearly independent and uncorrelated
  11. $x_1$ and $y$ are two independent variables "rendered dependent" by observations on their effect, $x_2$
- If $\beta_1 \ne 0$:

  1. $x_1$ is linear cause of $y$ (more umbrellas cause wetter sidewalks)
  2. $y$ is linear cause of $x_1$ (wetter sidewalks cause more umbrellas)
  3. $Z$ is linear cause of $x_1$ AND $y$ (more rain, GDP,... causes both)
  4. []
  5. $Cor(x_1,y) \ne 0$ and linearly dependent but no causal chain, parent, or child

**Are the final three choices mutually exclusive and exhaustive if we are correct that $\beta_1 \ne 0$? Illustrative examples would help.**

*Note, when I say "cause," I do not mean the direct, immediate cause, but instead that there is a shared causal chain from $l,m,n, ... \to x_1 \to p,q,r,... \to y$. Also, $\beta_1 \ne 0$. $\hat\beta_1$ is irrelevant.

Suggested additions that I dispute (but open to change):

4. $x_1$ and $y$ are (jointly) linear cause(s) of $x_2$ (less heat and more water cause more time to boil water)

   - if this is not really a case of (3), hence new example, then it seems we incorrectly concluded that $\beta_1 \ne 0$ with two independent variables ($x_1$ and $y$) such as heat and water quantity. (I think "independent variables" $\to \beta_1 = 0 \to$ (10), not (4))
   - also violates multicollinearity assumption needed for $\hat{\beta_1} = \beta_1$ ($x_1$ and $x_2$ should be linearly independent and uncorrelated).
   - [Berkson's paradox???](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkson%27s_paradox)
5. $x_1$ and $y$ have no linear causal relationships at all ([margarine consumption/capita $\to$ divorces in Maine/capita(k)](http://tylervigen.com/view_correlation?id=1703))

   - then it seems we incorrectly concluded that $\beta_1 \ne 0$. ($\beta_1 = 0 \to$ (10), not (5))
   - time-series autocorrelation (of values and/or errors) may pose a problem??
   - what is the population from which these values represent a random sample?
   - if this is the "population", $N=10$, how do we talk about it?
   - $Z \to x_1,y$ is true but unbelievable with current knowledge

Comment: **No.** Some readings that may help you understand how to weave causal inference into your statistical models: Greenland, S., Pearl, J., and Robins, J. M. (1999). Causal diagrams for epidemiologic research. *Epidemiology*, 10(1):37–48. and Maldonado, G. and Greenland, S. (2002). Estimating causal effects. *International Journal of Epidemiology*, 31(2):422–438.

Comment: For more depth, see also: Pearl, J. (2000). *Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference*. Cambridge University Press. And the forthcoming Hernán, M. A. and Robins, J. M. (2015). *Causal Inference*. Chapman & Hall/CRC.

Comment: Note also that $\beta_1= 0$ is perfectly compatible with the idea that $x_1$ causes $x_2$, which causes $y$.

Comment: @Scortchi: or just $x_1$ causes $y$, but not linearly.

Comment: "If we correctly reject the null hypothesis...":  Note that one would not be justified in saying that in the population B1 is 99.9% likely to be nonzero.  One could say that if the null were true, 99.9% of sample B1's would be closer to zero than the observed one.

Comment: @jtd: What multicollinearity assumption? You can hardly insist that $x_1$ & $x_2$ are completely uncorrelated in an observational data-set. And nothing you say there implies perfect collinearity between them.

Comment: @NeilG: Very good point, often overlooked.

Comment: I would also like to point out that a significant regression coefficient could also mean there is no causal relationship at all! I would be suspect of any causal chain that implies [eating margarine causes divorce in Maine](http://tylervigen.com/view_correlation?id=1703).  To get at true causation, experimental design (like randomized intervention) is needed. To the recommended readings, I would add: Pearl, J (2009) Causal Inference in Statistics. Particularly section 2.

Comment: @Joshua: Thanks! First, this is why I wish regression p-value were more sensitive to micro $n$ and set my $n=1,000$. Note largest $n$ on SC is 20. Second, I now have (at least) 3 routes with your example: (a) we incorrectly rejected null hypothesis, $\beta_1 = 0 \to (10)$, (b) we correctly rejected null but there is confusion about the conceptual population that data represents and the causal statement you are rejecting, and (c) we correctly rejected null hypothesis and really $\beta_1 \ne 0 \to (1 (marge \to divorce), 2 (divorce \to marge) , 3 (Z \to marge + divorce)$. Do a,b,c work for you?

Comment: @Scortchi: I updated response to (4) to avoid full reliance on multicollinearity suggestion but both suggestions point to something like "independence requirements." Are these suggestions persuasive?

Comment: @jtd I don't think any of those three are justified given a regression alone. I think my ultimate issue is this (similar to your other post on this subject). In none of these discussions have you mentioned _how_ you controlled causal forces to make your inference regarding causation. You've only presented a significant regression coefficient, which is based on the distribution assumptions of linear regression. As Pearl discusses, this is _associational_ as it can be completely defined by variable distributions (which she specifically defines regression as associational)...cont...

Comment: ...cont... To make a _causal_ inference, you need an experimental design (intervention, randomization, spurious correlation, etc) that manipulates or controls for the causal forces you would infer.

Comment: I'll also point out that this _doesn't_ mean that we incorrectly concluded that $\beta \ne 0$. $x_1$ can be predictive of $y$. There still can be an association, but no causation is shown.

Comment: @joshua: who is "she"?  Also, you do not *need* intervention and randomization as discussed in Pearl's book.  You can make causal conclusions via the front door method or back door method.

Comment: @Neil That would be a typo. I was referring to Judea Pearl's 2009 paper, Causal inference in statistics: An overview.

Comment: @Neil I'm not limiting the options to intervention and randomization, just mentioning them as examples where design is needed to justify causation, beyond just the claim that a regression coefficient is significant. A significant regression coefficient, standing alone, only offers justification for prediction and association, not causation.

Comment: @joshua you're right.

Comment: @jtd: No - there's no requirement that predictors be uncorrelated.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're asking if two variables $x_1, y$ are dependent, which causal relationships between them might account for the dependence.

You pointed out three.  A fourth is the following where neither is the cause of the other, nor do they have a common cause:

$x_1 \rightarrow x_2 \leftarrow y$.

Or in general something like this.  For example,

$x_1 \rightarrow a \leftarrow b \rightarrow c \leftarrow y$ where $a \rightarrow x_2 \leftarrow c$.

Your choices are not mutually exclusive because there could also be a common cause $z$.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand your arrows or your fourth possibility. Could you give an illustrative example of an $x_1$ and $y$ that are dependent and meet all assumptions as in original question that clearly is your (4) (or clearly does not fall into 1-3)?

Comment: @jtd:  What don't you understand?  If $x_1$ and $y$ are the causes of $x_2$, they will appear dependent given that $x_2$ is observed.

Comment: (I should say, "may" appear dependent.  They could nevertheless remain independent.)

Comment: Does your (4) violate multicollinearity, striking it off our updated list?

Comment: @jtd: Just rearrange the terms in your equation so that $x_2$ is a function of $y$ and $x_1$.  Why is anything violated?  Anyway, the linear relationship doesn't tell you anything about the actual direction of causality — just that things are dependent.

Comment: My thinking is: if this is NOT a case of (3), then $x_1$ and $y$ are independent (causes of $x_2$ or latent $x_3$), and thus we have incorrectly rejected the null hypothesis because $\beta_1 = 0$ leading to (10) not (4).

Comment: @jtd but $\beta_1$ won't be zero because $x_1$ and $y$ won't be independent given observation of $x_2$.  A pair of common causes can be rendered dependent by observation of their effect.

Comment: I may ask a new question about Berkson's paradox but my sense is that $\beta_1 = 0$ (they are independent) but spuriously *appear* dependent due to paradox?

Comment: @jtd I don't think that paradox is applicable to your example.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is it a math misunderstanding between fourfold tables and linear regression? Your comment, "A pair of common.." sounded exactly like Berkson, or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @jtd why don't you try to build some examples where all your variables are binary and you have the linear relationships you want?

Comment: Sorry, it sounds like you are suggesting that Berkson's paradox is not applicable to linear regression where (at least) $y$ must be a continuous variable, but I am not sure that is what you mean? Or maybe you say, "The result is that two independent events become conditionally dependent (negatively dependent) given that at least one of them occurs" is BP but that is not what you mean in "A pair of common"? Or maybe you mean, "A pair of common" is not a fancy paradox, it's just a fact of regression that observations on $x_2$ may render $x_1$ and $y$ dependent? Apologies.

Comment: @jtd: why does anything have to be continuous?  The examples on the wikipedia page are not continuous.  Did you look at the wikipedia page?  You need to make some examples so that you can discover for yourself the problems with your intuition.